# Проверка сокета на доступность

Tags: c++, boost

Пусть кто-то отправляет сообщение на мой сокет, он его принимает функцией `receive_from(asio::buffer(buffer, size), SenderEndPoint)`, где `SenderEndPoint` из `boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint`. Затем, я отвечаю через `send_to(asio::buffer(buffer2), SenderEndPoint)` для тот же `SenderEndPoint`.

Но есть одна проблема: если тот, кто изначально послал сообщение закрыл сокет, то программа вылетает с исключением. Пробовал окружить отсылку `try-catch` с исключениями и из `std::exception`, и из `boost::exception`, но почему-то этот эксепшн ловится гораздо более верхним `try-catch` из `main`(это все дело, которое я описал выше происходит в объекте класса).

Можно ли как-то сделать проверку на доступность сокета у отправляющего, если используется `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket` для приема и отправки на моей стороне?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прилет исключения в main вполне логичен - это же асинхронное выполнение. Ловите его там и реагируйте, как вам нужно.

Comment: Это, конечно, может являться решением, но вопрос все-таки был: можно ли проверить `SenderEndPoint` на доступность?

Comment: единственный нормальный способ проверить, что в соедниение существует и в него  можно писать - это попытаться туда записать. Все остальные способы либо сводятся к этому, либо не работают:)